# Which engine does Stack Exchange use to switch skins on different sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Stack Exchange sites are similar in logic but different in skins. Do they use some engine to accomplish this?

Where can I read about Stack Exhange internals?

Comment: see: [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/165773)

Answer (score 3):

> Do they use some engine to accomplish this?

Most of the styling will be done using a [CSS (Cascading Style Sheet)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) file which allows having the same (or similar) HTML structure across sites, but with vastly different designs.

> Where to read about stackexchange internals at all?

There is this question: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Then a number of Stack Exchange employees has blogs on which they occasionally talk about their work.

Off the top of my head:

- [Balpha](http://balpha.de/)
- [Waffles](http://samsaffron.com/) (Ex-Stack Exchange)
- [Nick Craver](http://nickcraver.com/blog/)
- [Kevin Montrose](http://kevinmontrose.com/)

I'm sure this list is incomplete and I'm forgetting people.

Comment: You should add this list to your answer, the list of [Stack Exchange Team Members](http://stackexchange.com/about/team), which will help supplement your incomplete list. ;)